# Assigning horizonatal div's height dynamically

Tags: html, css

Hi I have an issue in assigning height dynamically to div areas.

Following is a demo layout type that I need to generate.

[image]

According to `Dynamic content 1` and `Dynamic content 2` the Gray color div automatically adjust its height as I have defined `Height:auto` in that layout. Thats fine.

The problem that I encounter is how to dynamically set the same height for side Div layouts(which I have indicated in Orage color). I tried with the following HTML and CSS but it doesn't work to get the height automatically in orange colored divs...

following is the HTML and CSS i tried with.

```
<div style="margin: auto; width: 510px; height: auto;">

        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 100%; background-color: Orange; vertical-align: top;">
        </div>

        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 450px; height: auto; vertical-align: top; margin-left: -4px; margin-right: -4px; background-color: #bebebe;">
            <div style="margin: auto; width: 200px; height:50px; background-color:Green; text-align:center"> Dynamic content 1 </div>
            <div style="margin: auto; width: 200px; height:50px; background-color:Olive; text-align:center"> Dynamic content 2 </div>
        </div>

        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 30px; height: 100%; background-color: Orange; vertical-align: top;">
        </div>

</div>
```

Following is the result I am getting for the above HTML.

[image]

It doesn't assign the height property automatically for the side divs. Even for the Right hand side div.

Not sure what I am doing wrong and would grateful if can guide me in where I am going wrong in this case. Thanks....

**NOTE**

The side orage colred divs are not borders.

Comment: A http://jsFiddle.net with the relevant code makes such problems really easy for us to fix and explain

Comment: Your welcome http://jsfiddle.net/dgjas/

Comment: If your markup can be changed, how about doing it [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/dgjas/2/) way? (Floating the parent div and then clearing the float)

Comment: Just noticed this (*The side orage colred divs are not borders.*) in the question. If this means the orange divs can have content then ignore the above comment :)

Comment: Yes, I need to add a div to that orange colored ares as there going to be content in those areas as well..... In the question I used different colors to make the question easilly understood.... Problem is I want both those divs(The ones I have showed in Orange color) exaclty in the same height of the middle div(Gray colored div).. Thanks

Comment: @JibW: Ok, in that case you should try Danield's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) add `display:table` to the container div. and

2) give your 'orange' divs `display:table-cell`

(Chrome doesn't require step 2, but other browsers like FF and IE do.)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TKJ5k/1/)**

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But still it doesn't have orange colored divs displaying which means the height haven't assigned yet.... When I click your FDDLE link in the Answer it loads without the orage colored divs.... I want a layout as my first Image(Top image) In question.... Thanks..

Comment: hmm it's working by me on chrome, I'll check this in other browsers

Comment: @JibW - I updated my answer - it's now working in FF and IE too.

Comment: +1 mate, its working now :) you should mark that 2nd point as important (for the sake of future readers)

Comment: @Harry - I made a note of that in my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div style="text-align:center; margin: auto; width: 510px; height: auto; background-color: Orange; vertical-align: top;">
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 450px; height: auto; vertical-align: top; margin-left: -4px; margin-right: -4px; background-color: #bebebe;">
<div style="margin: auto; width: 200px; height:50px; background-color:Green; text-align:center"> Dynamic content 1 </div>
<div style="margin: auto; width: 200px; height:50px; background-color:Olive; text-align:center"> Dynamic content 2 </div>
</div></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dgjas/3/

Comment: Hi Thanks for the Answer. I need to use those areas that I have idicated in orange color to Add some content in real use. That's why I am trying to use a seperate div to those areas... Just to make the question easy to understand only I have Used colors. That area is not going to use as a BORDER.... Also in your answer You haven't use any closing tag(</div>) for first two Divs. Thank you once again for the Answer....

Comment: Hi, yes, corrected the above. The closing divs were not code formatted and thus skipped (also forgot one of them in the fiddle at the end). Overall, Danields table approach is better suited for your needs